# Recording sounds created within an iPhone app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, audio-recording

I'm new to programming in Objective-c and the iPhone but I am working on an app to teach myself. I have been trying to figure out how to record sounds on the iPhone. Apple provides excellent documentation for recording from the microphone with AVAudioRecorder but I want to record sounds made by my app, or even just record sounds when buttons are pressed (button is pressed, certain audio gets recorded).
I have no clue how to do this and can't seem to find anything that would help me along this path, only microphone stuff.
Can anyone share ideas or code that would make this possible?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you move beyond the convenience classes like `AVAudioRecorder`, you've got a lot of studying to do.

I would start with:

[Getting Started with Audio and Video](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/GS_AudioVideo_iPhone/index.html)

[Multimedia Programming Guide:Audio](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/MultimediaPG/UsingAudio/UsingAudio.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009767-CH2)

[Core Audio Overview](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/MusicAudio/Conceptual/CoreAudioOverview/Introduction/Introduction.html)

Audio programming is a very large and complex subject. If you want to customize, be prepared to spend some time learning it.

Answer (score 0):

I've made a sample app that records sounds/audio and has a playback. Hope this helps! https://github.com/casspangell/AudioMic